# EOQ - how to calculate holding cost

Tags: cost

This is very simple, however, I have the following setup

*Suppose that the company ABC has a product that shows a constant
annual demand rate of 3600 items. One item costs £3.
Ordering cost is £20 per order and holding cost is 25% of the value of inventory.*

What I want to do is calculate the **EOQ**

$$
EOQ = \sqrt{\frac{2DS}{H}}
$$

Where

- D = annual demand (here this is 3600)
- S = setup cost (here that's £20)
- H = holding cost
- P = Cost per unit (which is £3 here)

I figured that I would have

$$
H = 0.25 \times 3 = 0.75
$$

I'm sceptical about this result though.

Comment: This seems to give $EOQ \approx 438$. Do you think this looks too large or too small?

Comment: Note that for the formula to be correct, $H$ must be holding cost _per unit per year_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your EOQ expression is suggesting that the optimal order size is for about $438$ items each time.

You can check the result if you wish.  Suppose you order in batches of $Q$:

- The average annual number of batches ordered is $\dfrac{3600}{Q}$ so the average annual cost of ordering is $£\dfrac{72000}{Q}$
- The average number of items held in inventory is $\dfrac Q2$ worth $£\dfrac{3Q}{2}$ at a holding cost of $£\dfrac{3Q}{8}$
- So the combined ordering and holding cost is  $£\dfrac{72000}{Q}+£\dfrac{3Q}{8}$
- For $Q=437$ this gives about $£328.6347$; for $Q=438$ this gives about $£328.6336$; for $Q=439$ this gives about $£328.6341$. This suggests that $438$ may indeed be the best order size
- You can check the calculus: the derivative of $\dfrac{72000}{Q}+\dfrac{3Q}{8}$ is $\dfrac{3}{8} - \dfrac{72000}{Q^2}$ which is a increasing function of $Q$ and is zero when $Q^2=192000$ i.e. $Q \approx 438.178$, and this would minimise the combined cost